# Two custom methods/endpoints using loopBack, one works, the other gives a 401

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, loopbackjs

I created two custom endpoints with Loopback.

```
Account.deleteAllHearingTests = function (req, callback) {
    console.log('here comes the req to delete all hearing tests', req);
    Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
        .then(account => {
            if (!account) {
                throw new Error('cannot find user');
            }
            return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll({ accountId: account.id }, { isDeleted: new Date() });
        })
        .then(() => {
            callback(null);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            callback(error);
        })
}
Account.remoteMethod(
    'deleteAllHearingTests', {
        http: {
            path: '/clearHearingTests',
            verb: 'post'
        },
        accepts: [
            { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } }
        ],
        returns: {}
    }
);
```

the second one looks like this.

```
Account.deleteSingleHearingTest = function (req, callback) {
        // console.log('accounts.js: deleteSingleHearingTest: are we being reached????', req)
        Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
            .then(account => {
                if (!account) {
                    throw new Error('Cannot find user');
                }
                console.log('account.js: deleteSingleHearingTest: req.body.hearingTestId    N: ', req.body.hearingTestId);
                return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll({ accountId: account.id, id: req.body.hearingTestId }, { isDeleted: new Date() });

            })
            .then(() => {
                callback(null);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                callback(error);
            });
    }

    Account.remoteMethod(
        'deleteSingleHearingTest', {
            http: {
                path: '/deleteSingleHearingTest',
                verb: 'post'
            },
            accepts: [
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', description: 'removes a single hearing test', http: { source: 'req' } }
            ],
            description: 'this is the end point for a single delete',
            returns: {}
        }
    );

};
```

The first custom method returns a 401 status response when I make the initial fetch.  The second returns a 200.

Inside my actions file the first method is called with something that looks like this:

```
export function deleteAllHearingTests() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let state = getState();
        if (!state.user || !state.user.accessToken || !state.user.accessToken.id || !state.user.accessToken.userId) {
            console.debug('deleteAllHearingTests', state.user);
            // TODO: ERROR
            return;
        }
        fetch(SERVERCONFIG.BASEURL + '/api/Accounts/clearHearingTests?access_token=' + state.user.accessToken.id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: SERVERCONFIG.HEADERS
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('here is your response', response);
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error('Something is wrong');
                }
                return response.json()
            })
```

the second method is called with

```
export const deleteSingleHearingTest = (hearingTestNumber) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let state = getState();
        if (!state.user || !state.user.accessToken || !state.user.accessToken.id || !state.user.accessToken.userId) {
            console.debug('writeTestResult', state.user);
            // TODO: ERROR
            return;
        }
        console.log('single delete ', SERVERCONFIG.BASEURL + '/api/Accounts/deleteSingleHearingTest?access_token=' + state.user.accessToken.id)
        fetch(SERVERCONFIG.BASEURL + '/api/Accounts/deleteSingleHearingTest?access_token=' + state.user.accessToken.id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: SERVERCONFIG.HEADERS,
            body: JSON.stringify({ "hearingTestId": hearingTestNumber })


        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('getting response from initial fetch inside deleteSingleReqport', response);
```

They are nearly identical, however, one works..the other fails.  What are some possible causes for the 401?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call those methods with external tool like a postman, so you would exactly know if you don't miss access_token or something else? Also, when you compare code from one function and another, you can see that you are colling the `updateAll` with different arguments. It's hard to say without original code, but maybe the issue is there? Compare below:

```
return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll(
    { accountId: account.id }, 
    { isDeleted: new Date() });

return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll(
    { accountId: account.id, id: req.body.hearingTestId }, 
    { isDeleted: new Date() });
```

Additionally, in `fetch` method they are also diffferences, you are missing in one case the below:

```
    body: JSON.stringify({ "hearingTestId": hearingTestNumber })
```

What you could also do to debug and to provide more data is to run server in debug mode by calling:

```
export DEBUG=*; npm start
```